# Bayesian Credible interval in Poisson Regression

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, credible-interval

Assume that $\pmb{y} = (y_1,...,y_n)$ are count data which depends on a dummy predictor $\pmb{x}$ (x = 0 if male, x = 1 if female) such that :
\begin{align}
\pmb{y} \sim Poisson(\lambda) 
\end{align}
With $\lambda$ being :
$$
log(\lambda) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i 
$$
If after fitting a Bayesian GLM with appropriate priors, I get the following credibles intervals for parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ :
$$ CI_{\beta_0} = [a,b] $$
$$ CI_{\beta_1} = [c,d] $$

Is it then correct to specify the credible interval for $\lambda$ for the male and female population are :

1. Male population :
   $$
    CI_{\lambda} = \big[exp(a+c\times 0)\ ; \ exp(b + d x 0)] = [exp(a) \ ; \ exp(b) \big]
   $$
2. Female population :
   $$
   CI_{\lambda} = \big[exp(a+c) \ ; \ exp(b + d) \big]
   $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log(\lambda) = \beta_0$ for the male population. So you get a credible interval of $\lambda$ by taking the exponentials of the bounds of the credible interval of $\beta_0$.

For the female population, $\log(\lambda) = \beta_0 + \beta_1$. Adding the bounds of the credible intervals of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ to get a credible interval of $\beta_0 + \beta_1$ is not correct. If you have some simulations of the posterior distribution, for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, you can add them to get simulations of the posterior distribution of $\beta_0 + \beta_1$, and take the exponential to get simulations of the posterior distribution of $\lambda$. Then you can construct a credible interval of $\lambda$ from these simulations, e.g. the equi-tailed credible interval by taking the quantiles, or the HPD interval.